# Optional Object Parameter in Web API 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

```
public async someReturnType PostSomething(long id, long someOptionalLong = 0);
```

The above code works and is the standard use-case. But what if I want my optional parameter to be of type SomeClass?

```
public async someReturnType PostSomething(long id, SomeClass someOptionalParam = null);
```

The above gives an error and says that it's not allowed. How do I pass an optional class instance param?

Answer (score 0):

```
SomeClass classInstanceOptionalParam = default(SomeClass);
```

Web API doesn't have a problem with this, though I thought it's suppose to always be null for reference types? Oh well. Don't think that this is a good answer, but at least it's not throwing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Web Api supports null values as parameters by default, but to force Web API to read a complex type from the URI, add the `[FromUri]` attribute to the parameter. so your api method would be:

```
public async someReturnType PostSomething(long id,[FromUri]SomeClass someOptionalParam)
```